# Erro no package: sp ao iniciar o RStudio

Tags: r

Ao iniciar o RStudio aparece a seguinte mensagem: `Loading required package: sp`. Tento instalar o pacote `sp` e aparece a mensagem:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘sp’ is in use and will not be installed
```

Dessa forma, não consigo instalá-lo. Além disso, por conta desse erro, estou tendo dificuldades em chamar o pacote `dplyr`. Como faço para tirar esse erro?

Comment: Veja se tem um ficheiro `.RData` no seu *working directory*. Este ficheiro (isto é o nome completo, não é a extensão) guarda o ambiente do R quando se termina a sessão. É aí que deve estar a instrução para carregar o pacote `sp` logo no arranque.

Comment: Veja também `detach(unload = TRUE)` ou `unloadNamespace`, tal como está dito na página de ajuda `?library`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas tive que instalar novamente.